# Selenium (python). Can't find correct way to click on button

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

There is html where I can't find correct way to click on button via selenium on python.

[Here is the part of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysoA6.png)

So, I need to click on

```
class="standart-wallet_standartWalletText__zjyj3"
```

via selenium but it seems nothing work.

What I tried:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='standard wallet']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[starts-with(@class,'standart-wallet_standartWalletText')]"
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((CSS_SELECTOR, ...)))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((CLASS_NAME, ...)))
```

and so on...

What I got:

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

So, please help ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

The element is probably hidden, as it's nested in accordion. So it won't get `clickable` status until getting expanded. You can try to implement a function that expands it or simply use `EC.presence_of_element_located()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But still do not work. The same error ((

Comment: Without real page can't help you, maybe content is being dynamically when user opens the tab or something.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Flash Thunder. I found solution just via xpath method. 

`first_btn = '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[1]'`
`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, first_btn).click()`